# Removing first two digits of integer - assembly/nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

User inputs four digit number (lets say they enter 1960) I need to compare another number to the last two digits (60), but I'm stuck. The first two digits could be anything from 00-99, so I can't subtract 1900. I've tried manipulating binary, but no luck. any suggestions how i can get 60 from 1960, or 05 from 2005, ect.

Comment: Or, the simplistic but less efficient way is to make a loop that checks the value and keeps subtracting 100 from it until it goes below 100. The final result is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Data mod 100 ! (data % 100) 
Or divide and then take remainder. Same idea.

Answer (score 2):

Divide by 100 and use the remainder :

```
mov    dx, 0
mov    ax, 1960
mov    bx, 100
div    bx
;REMAINDER 60 IS IN DX.
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the first two digits when converting from string to integer in the first place.

Bitwise tricks can't help you, because 10 isn't a power of 2, so the high digits of a decimal number affect the low bits of the binary representation.

Comment: It's a nice idea to *not use the first two digits* but in practice there might be a huge gap between the time of input (where the numbers briefly exist as strings) and the time of use (where the compare takes place and the numbers merely exist as integers).

Comment: @SepRoland: yeah, that's true.  This is assembly language, though, where you can and should take advantage of every shortcut and opportunity when possible.  You'll probably have to rewrite it anyway if you want to use it as part of a larger program.  I didn't mention DIV (or using a modular multiplicative inverse to do it efficiently) because other answers already cover that more general / flexible solution.